# How can I use reflection to get a reference to a lambda that I can pass around?

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8

I can use reflection to dynamically get a method and call it. How can I do the same with a lambda? IE something like

```
class Foo{
    public static String mapper(Object o){
        return "dummy val";
    }
}

class Bar {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String[] arr = {"a", "b", "c"};
        Lambda reflectedMapper = ReflectionUtils.getLambda("Foo.mapper");//How do I actually write this line?
        List<String> mapped = arr.stream().map(reflectedMapper).collect(Collectors.toList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think a lambda is?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes, I know that I can get a reference to a lambda by statically writing it out (ie I could say `map(Foo::mapper)`). But how do I do that dynamically? How do I go from the string `Foo.mapper` to actually calling it?

Comment: @David A lambda is just a syntactic feature of the language. Lambdas in Java are just expressions that evaluate to objects. Therefore you would use the same reflection mechanisms that you would use to create other objects to do what you want to do.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo I would (did) use reflection to instantiate an instance of a `Method` class and try to pass that. It didn't work. Hence my question here.

Comment: you could accept this answer if it helped, btw.

Answer (score 6):

If I understood correctly, having this for example:

```
static class Test {
    public static boolean transform(String s) {
        return s.toUpperCase().equals("SOME");
    }
}
```

You can obtain the `Function` that you are looking for, like this:

```
MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, String.class);
MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
MethodHandle handle = lookup.findStatic(Test.class, "transform", methodType);
Function<String, Boolean> f = (Function<String, Boolean>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
                 lookup, 
                 "apply",
                 MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
                 methodType.generic(),
                 handle,
                 methodType)
            .getTarget()
            .invokeExact();
```

Also notice that this same method qualifies as a `Predicate` also; because it's signature is `String, boolean` and can be used as such:

```
  MethodType predicateMT = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, Object.class);
    MethodType stringPredicateMT = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, String.class);

    MethodType methodType = MethodType.methodType(boolean.class, String.class);

    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodHandle handle = lookup.findStatic(Test.class, "transform", methodType);
    Predicate<String> p = (Predicate<String>) LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(
            lookup, "test",
            MethodType.methodType(Predicate.class),
            predicateMT,
            handle,
            stringPredicateMT)
            .getTarget().invokeExact();


 System.out.println(p.test("Some"));
```